# AngularJs $routeProvider and $location with ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, angularjs

So I have been experimenting with AngularJs and I liked how you can use  **$routeProvider** in the **config** method to load partials as templates with Ajax calls.

So I did this:

```
var $app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

$app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/pop", {controller: "popCtrl", templateUrl: "partials/pop_test.html"})
    .when("/dashboard", {controller: "dashBoardCtrl", templateUrl: "partials/dashboard.html"})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: "/"})

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])
```

I think this is a great system to loading dynamic content but now this is the problem I am having.

I have a form:

```
<form ng-submit action="">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" ng-model="creds.username">
        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="creds.password">
        <input ng-click="login()" type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
```

in this form I am checking the value of creds.username and creds.password and if they match a username password object that I have, you are then able to load the dashboard.

I am not going to show the entire process of the login function because that will make things more confusing but I did a login function somewhere along the lines of this:

```
login = function(creds){
            if(creds.username == 'admin' && creds.password == '222'){
                $location.path('/dashboard');
            }else{
                alert("Wrong Credentials");
            }
        },
```

Now the issue here is that when the url changes to /dashboard it reloads the page instead of making the ajax call and loading my partial like with the **when method**

**So this made the Ajax call that loaded the partial:**

```
.when("/dashboard", {controller: "dashBoardCtrl", templateUrl: "partials/dashboard.html"})
```

**and when I redirect the page with $location.path it reloads the page instead of loading the partial with Ajax.**

```
$location.path('/dashboard');
```

I had believed that the routes that I set up in my app.js file would allow the page to make the ajax call but I think it would be because of the $location.path automatically reloading the page before the ajax call is made is why this is not working.

So the question here is how can I load my partial with Ajax like I did with Routes but with $location not reloading the page. Or do I have to do something else in order to do this?

Help is appreciated, thank you.

**UPDATE:**

So I left out one important information and that is my navigation links.

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pop">Pop</a></li>
        <li><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
    </ul>
```

if I click on them my routes work just fine and the page does not reload. I make an ajax call and my partials get loaded. But when I do this with

```
$location.path('/dashboard');
```

that's when the page gets reloaded and my partials do not get loaded in because my routes have been ignored.

Comment: Can you please update code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I would start trying this:
http://joelsaupe.com/programming/angularjs-change-path-without-reloading/

Basicly they rewrite the $location.path() function to take an extra parameter to specify if the page should be reloaded or not.